# Java Collection sort BigDecimal

Tags: java, android, collections, arraylist, bigdecimal

I'm trying to sort an ArrayList by BigDecimal and coming up against a brickwall.  I have a class that looks a little like this:

```
public class deal implements Comparable<deal>{

protected BigDecimal bdPrice;
protected int iQuantity;
protected String sDealType;
protected UUID dealUniqueID;
protected int dealID;
protected BigDecimal bdUnitPrice;

public deal(){
    bdPrice         = new BigDecimal("0");
    bdUnitPrice     = new BigDecimal("0");
    iQuantity       = 1;
    sDealType       = "Single item";
    dealUniqueID    = UUID.randomUUID();
    dealID          = 0;
}

private void setUnitPrice(){
    this.bdUnitPrice = this.bdPrice.divide(new BigDecimal(this.iQuantity));
}

public BigDecimal compareTo(deal oDeal) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return bdUnitPrice.compareTo(oDeal.getUnitPrice());
}

public boolean equals(deal oDeal) {
    if (!(oDeal instanceof deal))
        return false;
    deal oD = (deal) oDeal;

    return this.bdUnitPrice.equals(oD.bdUnitPrice);
}
}
```

and my main Android Activity looks like this:

```
public class SupermarketDealsActivity extends Activity {
private ArrayAdapter<deal> itemAdapter;
private ListView lvDeals;
private ArrayList<deal> itemArray;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    SetUpView();
}

private void SetUpView(){
lvDeals                     = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.listDeals);

    itemArray                   = new ArrayList<deal>();
    itemArray.clear();

    itemAdapter                 = new ArrayAdapter<deal>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,itemArray);
    lvDeals.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
}

private void CreateADeal(int iQuantity, BigDecimal bdPrice) {
    deal oDeal                  = new deal();

    oDeal.setQuantity(iQuantity);
    oDeal.setPrice(bdPrice);

    CreateListDeals(oDeal);
}

private void CreateListDeals(deal oDeal){
    itemArray.add(oDeal);
    Collections.sort(itemArray,Collections.reverseOrder());
    itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

In my java class I am getting an error with my compareTo method saying:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to BigDecimal

I must have missed something along the way, what is it?

Cheers

Comment: compareTo shouldn't return BigDecimal.

Comment: ok, but how do i go about comparing and sorting by my unitprices which are in BigDecimal format... do i convert it to string?

Comment: No, you change the return type of your `compareTo` to fit the correct signature for the interface.

Comment: You might want to consider `SortedSet` implementations (`TreeSet` in other words), and possibly read up on the correct case to use for identifiers, e.g. in the [code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

Comment: 1AM brain fart, of course you return int...  cheers Paul Tomblin.  @owlstead i'll check that SortedSet out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public BigDecimal compareTo(deal oDeal) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return bdUnitPrice.compareTo(oDeal.getUnitPrice());
}
```

Does not match either the signature of the interface, nor does it match the return type of `bdUnitPrice.compareTo`.  Change it to:

```
public int compareTo(deal oDeal) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return bdUnitPrice.compareTo(oDeal.getUnitPrice());
}
```

A couple of other things I should mention (from the comments):

1. The names of classes should start with an upper case letter.  There is a "[code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)" document that spells out that and other things you should do.
2. You override `equals` - you should never override `equals` unless you also override `hashCode` - otherwise you'll have tons of problems if you put the objects of this class into a HashSet, HashMap or other collection which uses hash.

Comment: Also don't forget to override the "hashcode" method, which you should do anytime you change the ".equals" method.  You'll find that hashmaps and like won't work properly otherwise.

Comment: Good point, @Matt.  One thing I like to recommend to anybody doing Java is to install the FindBugs plugin, which will warn you about things like that.

Comment: This one of the nice things that Eclipse can do for you.  There's a menu item for "Generate hashCode() and equals()".  You select the fields to use in the comparison, and it generates the corresponding has for you as well as the .equals method :)